PHPSpreadsheet, how do I set different layout for each series in a composite graph?
I am trying to create charts in excel using the PHP library PHPSpreadSheet. But when I generate a composite graph with multiple types of graphs together, I get overlapping data labels.
Stacked bar + Area graph
In the code we can set data labels visible/invisible, but it makes every label visible/invisible. I only want to hide label for area chart.
    $layout = new Layout();
    $layout->setShowVal(true);
    // $layout->setDLblPos('inBase');
    // Set the series in the plot area
    $plotArea = new PlotArea($layout, [$series, $series3]);

Any suggestions?
